# 2 Columns with variable width using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a products list with an image, title and price.
At the top I have the image and underneath it the title and the price.

The problem is that the price an title have a variable length. The price should take up al the space it needs and the title can take the remaining space. How can this be accomplished?

Example:

[image: Example of product item]

The image above is not coded, it's what I want to accomplish. The html code is very basic:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="..."/>
        </div>
        <div class="product-bottom">
            <div class="title">
                <h3><a href="...">...</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                &euro; 199<sup>99</sup>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide code. so i can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use display `table` and `table-cell` - give a width to the price column that is smaller than the price and no width to the title and it will always stretch the price column if bigger.  You can then vertical align too

```
.product-bottom {display:table;}
.title,
.price {display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
.price {width:10px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b3cb1dq9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to help you, but you can make the price-tag a span width a defined padding, while the title should have a `text-overflow:ellipsis`, and also `white-space:nowrap;` and also float left and right

Comment: The problem is that ellipsis and nowrap will only work for a single line.